# Why am I getting a 403 from Spring-Security when setting permitAll?

Tags: spring-security

I have the following code:

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
            .requestMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
    );
    http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
    http.headers((headers) -> headers
            .frameOptions((frame) -> frame
                    .disable()
            )
    );
    return http.build();
}
```

but when I attempt to hit the h2-console endpoint, I receive a 403 error:

```
curl -v http://localhost:8080/h2-console
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
...
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 403
```

If I modify the authenticated to permitAll, i.e., `.anyRequest().permitAll()`, it functions perfectly fine.

How can I configure the code to restrict access to h2-console and all its sub-paths but is blocked for all other paths?

**Update**

Per the suggestion I tried this...

```java
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    private static RequestMatcher h2ConsoleRequestMatcher() {
        return new RequestMatcher() {
            @Override
            public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {
                String path = request.getServletPath();
                return path.startsWith("/h2-console");
            }
        };
    }
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // TODO: 2021-10-13 - remove permitAll() and add proper security
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                .requestMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
        );
        http.csrf((csrf) ->
                csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers(h2ConsoleRequestMatcher())
                        .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
        );
        http.headers((headers) -> headers
                .frameOptions(
                        HeadersConfigurer.FrameOptionsConfig::disable
                )
        );
        return http.build();
    }
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> corsFilter() {
        CorsConfiguration corsConfig = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfig.setAllowCredentials(true);
        corsConfig.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:3000");
        corsConfig.addAllowedHeader("*");
        corsConfig.addAllowedMethod("*");

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfig);

        FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> bean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(0);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

But I still get the 403...

```
curl http://localhost:8080/h2-console -v
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /h2-console HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.87.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 403
```

Thanks to the accepted answer below here is the final working version

```java
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/actuator/**")).permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/h2-console/**")).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
        );
        http.csrf((csrf) ->
                csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/h2-console/**"))
                        .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
        );
        http.headers((headers) -> headers
                .frameOptions(
                        HeadersConfigurer.FrameOptionsConfig::disable
                )
        );
        return http.build();
    }
```

Comment: Please share your controller class.

Comment: h2-console isn't a controller it is added auto by the library if configured (http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html)

Comment: Also the console works fine if I remove the authenticated and add permitAll so I know it is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `requestMatchers("a_string_path")` will map to a `MvcRequestMatcher`

> If the [HandlerMappingIntrospector](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/HandlerMappingIntrospector.html) is available in the classpath, maps to an [MvcRequestMatcher](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/servlet/util/matcher/MvcRequestMatcher.html) that does not care which HttpMethod is used. This matcher will use the same rules that Spring MVC uses for matching. For example, often times a mapping of the path **"/path"** will match on **"/path", "/path/"**, **"/path.html"**, etc. If the HandlerMappingIntrospector is not available, maps to an AntPathRequestMatcher.
> **If a specific RequestMatcher must be specified, use requestMatchers(RequestMatcher...)** instead
> Params:
> patterns – the patterns to match on. The rules for matching are defined by Spring MVC if MvcRequestMatcher is used
> Returns:
> the object that is chained after creating the RequestMatcher.
> Since:
> 5.8

So for accessing the **h2-console** with its own Servlet, you need to use an [AntPathRequestMatcher](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/util/matcher/AntPathRequestMatcher.html)

This should work:

```java
.requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/h2-console/**")).permitAll()
```

---

An alternative is to provide a extra [WebSecurityCustomizer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityCustomizer.html) bean.

```java
@Bean
//@Profile("dev")
WebSecurityCustomizer h2ConsoleSecurityCustomizer() {
 return web -> 
      web.ignoring().requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/h2-console/**"));
}
```

Comment: How that second one is exactly what I was looking for let me try it out! Thank you so much!

Comment: Worked with the regular version now to try with the profile! That matches the Spring Profile rt? Even if I pass multiple as long as one of them is correct it should match rt?

Comment: Yes, you can use multiple profiles on a @Bean like: `@Profile({"dev","test"})`, the Bean will be created when one or more of the profiles is active

Answer (score -1):

This behavior occurs because the default Spring Security configuration includes protection against CSRF attacks, and the /h2-console endpoint is affected by this protection. When CSRF protection is enabled, the requests to the /h2-console endpoint require a valid CSRF token to be included.

To resolve this issue, you can configure Spring Security to exempt the /h2-console endpoint from CSRF protection.

Add this into your SecurityFilterChain  to disable the csrf :

```
http.csrf((csrf) -> csrf
                .ignoringAntMatchers("/h2-console/**")
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
);
```

Comment: So the ignoringAntMatchers doesn't exist anymore and I tried the still available 

csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers("/h2-console/**")

But It still gives me a 403

Comment: I combined your answer with the one below and everything works. Not sure if I still need the csrf stuff but I left it in there anyway